# The Role of Du'as in religion and Qurb e Elahi?

Tags: shiism, dua

According to Shia, there are many du'as refering to ahl al=bait narrated in many books as Sahifa Sajjadiah, Mafatih al-Janan, Iqbal and Mesbah.... that are considarable.What is the role and postion of dua in religion and qurb e elahi? Is there any thing else with du'a, except qurb e elahi?

Answer (score -1):

Quran teaches us that by dua we can reach what we wish.

Dua is ordered by God.

**And your Lord says, "Call upon Me; I will respond to you." Indeed, those who disdain My worship will enter Hell [rendered] contemptible. 40:60**

Dua is talking and relation with God and makes us relax.

**Those who have believed and whose hearts are assured by the remembrance of Allah . Unquestionably, by the remembrance of Allah hearts are assured." 13:28**